# Break not working in <p> tag

Tags: html

I am struggling to get a break to work in my code. The break is not being recognised at all and just displays all text in one line.

I have tried a combination of using divs, spans and p tags, but still the same problem. I can only assume that the code i am using is illegal. I would be grateful if someone could clarify where I am going wrong. Thanks

[image]

```html
<div class="message">
    <div style="margin-top: 5px; font-size: 24px;">
        ALERT
    </div>
    <p>Landscape mode has been disabled in the app<br>
        Please continue by turning your device to protrait<br>
    Thank you
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats going on? whats the meaning of  your `Break`?

Comment: Breaking good..

Comment: The text appears on separate lines on my end. Could you post a screenshot of what it looks like for you?

Comment: You mean "alert" and the rest, or just "landscape..."?

Comment: I dont think any problme there. Read more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: @BO41 Just the txt below the alert. Thanks

Comment: @Daan Shot added. Thanks

Comment: The only way I can see this making any sense remotely, was if you had a rule in your stylesheet that set `br` elements to `display:none`, or something like that. But even then the words "app"/"Please" and "protrait"/"Thank" should not touch, because there is still white space between them besides the `br` element. Your code snippet here does not seem to reproduce what your screenshot shows at all, so please create a [mcve].

Comment: @CBoe many thanks. I had br set to none in my css which I totally missed. If you would like to supply as answer, I will gladly accept. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have `display:none` on all `<br>`. If using this doesn't work:

```
br {display:block}
```

try using JavaScript to override any `display` properties on all `<br>`

### Demo

```js
var brArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('br'));

brArray.forEach(function(brk, idx) {
  brk.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
/* There's a possibility thisproperty might be somewhere */
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* More than likely this is the culprit */
.message br {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert message">
  <div style="margin-top: 5px; font-size: 24px;">
    ALERT
  </div>
  <p>Landscape mode has been disabled in the app <br>Please continue by turning your device to protrait<br> Thank you
  </p>
</div>

<p>Click the text above</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have applied the following style to my label:
**white-space: pre-line;**

```css
#divWithPreline {
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 2px red;
}

#divWithoutPreline {
    border: solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="divWithPreline">
This is a div

whose content has line breaks

and the <b>white-space pre-line</b> has been applied
</div>
<br>
<div id="divWithoutPreline">
This is a div

whose content has line breaks

and <b>no styling</b> has been applied
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> OPTION 1: Add one more `<br>` in the second line.

The primary purpose of <`br>` is to insert a single line break. And this is how it is exactly working in your code. If you need an empty line above `Thank You`, just add one more `br>`.

```html
<div class="message">
    <div style="margin-top: 5px; font-size: 24px;">
        ALERT
    </div>
    <p>Landscape mode has been disabled in the app<br>
        Please continue by turning your device to protrait<br><br>
    Thank you
    </p>
</div>
```

> OPTION 2: You can wrap your text inside `<pre>` tag and style it
>   accordingly.

```css
.no-format{
    font-family: initial;
}
```

```html
 <div class="message">
    <div style="margin-top: 5px; font-size: 24px;">
        ALERT
    </div>
    <pre class="no-format">Landscape mode has been disabled in the app.
Please continue by turning your device to protrait.

Thank you
    </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is still the same. Did a codepen and it displayed ok. Guess there must be something my end stopping it working.

Comment: what is the <doctype> on your page ?

Comment: I am using html5. Thanks

Comment: Since I cannot see whats going on inside the alert, I would suggest you to wrap your contents inside a `<pre>` tag. Check above.